# Font use copyright in an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, xcode, fonts

I am about to release my iPhone App soon. I used `Helvetica`, which is included in XCode. I was wondering if I need to pay to use `Helvetica`. I have an Apple Developer Membership. I so where can I get a license for it. If not, please send me a link to confirm it.

Answer (score 6):

The fonts are part of the iOS platform.  You're not distributing them, you're just using them.  Apple is distributing them and they are responsible for paying for licenses and royalties.

This is the same as if you built a podcast app using the built in quicktime player.  You wouldn't be responsible for licensing the aac or mp3 decoders.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pay for it. If it's included by default in Xcode, you're fine.